# Cannot Reach Deleted Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

We're working on an app that will show a list of an employee's shifts. If a shift has already passed, we want to delete it from the array of shifts and therefore not print it to the DOM.

We are effectively deleting the object with the `delete` property of arrays. Doing this, we know that deleting will leave the object as `undefined`.
Yet when it prints on screen, the undefines appear (this part makes sense), but when we try to grab them with a function in order to fix this issue (we're going to copy the array without the undefines), we can't reach the undefines.

How do we snag the undefines?

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="shift in CurrentUser.orderedSchedule = (schedule | orderBy:Time.getSortingDate:false)">
        <p>Start time: {{Time.makeDate(shift.start)}} 
        {{Time.makeTime(shift.start)}}</p>
        <p>end time: {{Time.makeDate(shift.end)}} 
        {{Time.makeTime(shift.end)}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UserController.js**:

```
$scope.getShifts = function(){
    $scope.schedule = $scope.CurrentUser.user.shifts; //array of objects that gets printed on screen
    var now = new Date();
    for (var indexOfShift in $scope.schedule){ //checks each shift
        var start = $scope.schedule[indexOfShift].start; //date object, the start of the shift
        if(start instanceof Date){
            if(parseInt(start.getTime())-parseInt(now.getTime())<0){
                //if the 'future time' has already passed now
                //remove the shift
                alert(start+" is in the past");
                delete $scope.CurrentUser.user.shifts[indexOfShift]; //deleting shift
                $scope.schedule = $scope.CurrentUser.user.shifts; //trying to update that we removed it, so we can find undefined
            }
        }
    }
    for(var indexOfShift in $scope.schedule){ //looping shifts again to look for undef
        console.log($scope.schedule[indexOfShift]); //this prints all of them but the undefines don't appear
        if($scope.schedule[indexOfShift].start===undefined){ //we never hit this
            alert("found a blank one");
        }
    }
};
```

And here is a sample of what our user data with the shifts look like (an array of objects):

```
$scope.CurrentUser.user = [
    { 
        'name': 'John Smith',
        'shifts':[
                {'start':new Date(2012, 07, 27, 4, 44),
                'end': new Date(2012, 07, 27, 12, 21)
                },
                {'start':new Date(2014, 09, 09, 20, 02),
                'end': new Date(2014, 09, 10, 7, 06)
                }
        ]
    }
];
```

Why can't we reach the undefines? Where have they gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Splice for your case.

Delete in this case will only set the element as undefined:

> myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>
> delete myArray[0]
>
> myArray

result: [undefined, "b", "c", "d"]

Splice actually removes the element from the array:

> myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>
> myArray.splice(0, 2)
>
> myArray

result: ["c", "d"]

for more about splice: [Microsoft Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/wctc5k7s%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

FOR Example from Mizzila:

```
var myFish =["angel", "clown", "drum", "mandarin", "surgeon"];

//removes 1 element from index 3
removed = myFish.splice(3, 1);
//myFish is ["angel", "clown", "drum", "surgeon"]
//removed is ["mandarin"]
```

use this in your case.

```
 //delete $scope.CurrentUser.user.shifts[indexOfShift]; 
$scope.CurrentUser.user.shifts.splice(indexOfShift, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The for (var i in arr) loop will not loop through undefined items. Two solutions:

1. Instead of delete arr[indexOfShift], use arr[indexOfShift] = null;
2. Instead of for(var i in arr), use a numerical loop as follows:

for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++){
  // do something
}